# Nativescript contact-list plugin

Tags: angular, plugins, nativescript

I am using nativescript with angular to create a contact list application, and i am using the nativescript-contacts plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-contacts). The development is done on ios emulator on mac high sierra.
I follow the documentation, and all goes well until i reach the newContact.save(); point, at which my application goes black, and exits. When .save() is commented out, i can console log the newContact object and see that is properly set.

My component looks like so:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from '@angular/router’

import { NewCardService } from './newcard.service';
import * as Toast from 'nativescript-toast';

@Component({
 selector: "Contact",
 moduleId: module.id,
 templateUrl: "./contact.component.html",
 styleUrls: ["./contact-common.css", "./contact.component.css"]
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
    public first_name: string="";
    public last_name: string="";
    public profession: string="";
    public phone: number = null;
    public email: string="";


constructor( private router: Router,
             private appStorage: AppStorage,
             private newCardService: NewCardService
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {    }

submit(){
    const date = new Date();
    const newContact = {
        id:  this.last_name + date.getTime(),
        first_name : this.first_name,
        last_name : this.last_name,
        profession : this.profession,
        phone: this.phone,
        email: this.email
    }
    this.newCardService.saveToContactList(newContact)
    const toast = Toast.makeText("Saved!");
    toast.show();
    this.router.navigate(['home'])
}
}
```

The service for saving the contact looks like so:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import * as contacts from "nativescript-contacts";
import * as imageSource from "image-source" ;

@Injectable()
export class ContactService {

constructor(  private http: Http  ) { }

saveToContactList(contact) {
    var newContact = new contacts.Contact();
    newContact.name.given = contact.first_name;
    newContact.name.family = contact.last_name;
    newContact.phoneNumbers.push({ label: contacts.KnownLabel.WORK, value: contact.phone });
    newContact.organization = contact.profession
    newContact.photo = imageSource.fromFileOrResource(contact.cardPictureURL);
    newContact.save();
}
}
```

I have tried looking for solution to this problem, with no luck.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because of the more strict permission request in recent iOS versions. Try adding the following in your `app/App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist`

```
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires contacts access for whatever reason.</string>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! This was it. Adding this snippet, fixed the issue.
Ps. sorry for the delayed response.